# SoapClient header element attribute

Tags: php, soap

I have to add SOAP header like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <kontekstWywolania xmlns:wsu="http://namespace.xsd">
      <atrybut nazwa="idPodmiotuOidRoot">
         <wartosc>value</wartosc>
      </atrybut>
      <atrybut nazwa="idPodmiotuOidExt">
         <wartosc>anothervalue</wartosc>
      </atrybut>
   </kontekstWywolania>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Any ideas how to achieve that? Building whole thing using `\XMLWriter()` do not allow to use global namespaces (`<ns1:atrybut>` & `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns1="">`

Comment: Add to what ? Are you constructing your SOAP call manually or via http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: Have you tried building the header using http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse I did. I was not able to achieve this by using `\SoapHeader`. I was not able to add item param using `SoapHeader` or `SoapVar`. Yes, Im trying to use `\SoapClient`.